# How can I see the properties of every folder I open?

Tags: directory, disk-usage

I am new to Ubuntu, and am slowly getting used to it, so sorry if I mention that I miss one of the things from Windows. I used to be able to open folders and quickly see a reference, (usually on the left hand side corner, down) as to how many files this folder had and how many bites did it take in all.

Can I add this function? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its your file manager that displays that information. I assume you are using `nautilus` right now, try `thunar` it shows those info by default.

```
sudo apt-get install thunar
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it does the task! But it seems not to be worth the gain, the interface just does not cut it for me :)

Comment: I get ya, try setting display preferences for nautilus, it wont be exact same but you will be able to see count of contained folder/files below the folder icon. See if that helps, good luk.